# Failed review test - Why is this considered a valid question

Tags: support, specific-question, review-audits

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410296/what-were-the-c-idioms-for-polymorphism-and-inheritance-before-the-concepts-were) as I considered it to be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Don't get me wrong, its a lovely question, but it does not seem to conform to the Stack Overflow basic concept, i.e.

> here is my code and it is not doing what I expected. I put this in, I get this out, but I wanted it to produce something else.

Am I wrong in my assumption?

Can you educate me as to the true question requirements for a valid Stack Overflow question?

Comment: I think the review audits use pretty simple metrics to determine whether a test question is or isn't appropriate for the site - that question has 6 upvotes and 0 downvotes, so the system is probably considering it as a perfectly acceptable question (because that's what the community has currently indicated via voting).

Comment: Yes, but is it a valid SO type of question? I still dont think it is!

Comment: As much as SO questions should be about specific programming problems, I've noticed that more Programmers SE-style questions do seem to have a place here... Or at least they're accepted here by the general community.

Comment: A down vote??? I was after clarification, education, to help me be a better community member. I dont care about the Failed Test specifically. Oh whatever! There's at least one muppet in every group.

Comment: It's a good question.  Just because it doesn't include code/ask for debugging help doesn't make it off-topic.  Don't let the glut of crap on the front page fool you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Almost anything gets some downvotes on meta. They're handed out much more casually than on the main site

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I believe people are disagreeing with your assertion that this was a bad question. If we're closing well-asked programming questions like this, then people are making this site way too restrictive.

Comment: Thats fine, like I say I was after clarification and edjumakation, so its all good for me. If they disagree, tell me. This question may be useful for others in my situation, afterall thats what these sites are all about! Right???

Answer (score 3):

The question is about programming defined in the help-centre and it asks for facts instead of opinions therefore it's on-topic for SO. It may be considered too-broad by some people but I find it quite a good one and to the point.

I don't think this question fits your blueprint

In fact, your blueprint doesn't really fit the Stack Overflow "basic concept".

We are all here to **build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.** not to **help debug** every possible programming problem.

> here is my code and it is not doing what I expected.

There is some logical structure explained and the OP does not mention anything about it not working. It's a base information for the readers to help them better visualize the concept. It's exactly what we expect from askers, explain what you are doing and how you arrived at the point of asking a question.

I think the OP shows research by stating he's been through the linux kernel, some other projects trying to find an answer.

Also he tells us exactly how he has arrived at the question - had a student ask him directly.

> I put this in, I get this out, but I wanted it to produce something else.

Not really the case here, is it?

The actual question is:

> what is idiomatic C for inheritance and polymorphism?

which I find perfectly on-topic.

I would have left the question open if it pop-up as an audit.

Comment: Hmmm... If we're here to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming, what in there distinguishes us from Programmers SE? They're more for whiteboard-y programming questions, but those are still questions about programming...

Comment: @user3580294 please [re-read the TOUR on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) as well as [the Programmers SE help-center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see what is on-off topic there.

Comment: So looks like some questions fit on both sites. Makes sense, I suppose.

Comment: @user3580294 yes, they do.

Comment: @mehow Well I did read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and I would say it belongs in another site, quite possibly ProgrammersStack as you appear to be suggesting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it doesn't really "belong" there. It would probably be acceptable there as much as it is here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid.

> here is my code and it is not doing what I expected. I put this in, I get this out, but I wanted it to produce something else."

On what do you base the assumption that a question like that is the only acceptable question format on SO? The Help Center states:

> We **feel** the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question **generally** covers…
>
> > • a specific programming problem, or
> >
> > • a software algorithm, or
> >
> > • software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> >
> > • a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So I agree, it's not the kind of question SO was originally designed for, but this is more a guideline than canon law.

Plus the question you posted has a `history` tag. Which states:

> Use this tag for questions about the history of a programming concept or feature

**So questions about the history of programming related stuff is on-topic for SO.**

---

**Addendum:** Speaking of History related questions, I once asked why C# doesn't allow condition-less `while loops` while it does allow that for `for loops`. I posted a lot of research in the question itself going back from C to Algol, but a big-rep-user thought that was just plain silly to ask, and I believe it is now closed as opinion based while there exist a valid, factual and objective answer. (PS: Eric Lippert, if you read this... )

Comment: C#'s low-level looping constructs were designed to be familiar to users of C, C++ and Java. Were I to design a new language from scratch that does not have the requirement to be familiar to C, C++ and Java users, I would not re-invent anything even vaguely like the "for" loop syntax, which is *bizarre*.

Comment: I knew it! Thank you!